# Installing Ionic via Node.js fails

Tags: android, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I wanted to set up Ionic. So I downloaded and set up everything I needed to do so, but now if I want to download and install Ionic via Node.js with the command

npm install -g cordova ionic

I just get these errors, over and over again: 
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/f98eff-1432744817.png 
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/835599-1432744553.png

The installation of cordova seems to work since I can adress its commands already: 
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/e94db8-1432744749.png

So this works. But with Ionic I jsut receive the connection problems I wrote about here. Are there any suggestions why this happens?

Comment: I have already answered this, try following method explained here
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/31124491/1276616

Answer (score 0):

Try after cleaning npm cache using this command `npm cache clean`